# Cannot access nested data object from redux inside component

Tags: reactjs, redux

[image]

I am using react and redux and I have an object which is store on redux, above screenshot is the data state on redux being map to props inside a component:

```
class Users extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(fetchUsers());
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.users);
        return (
            <div className="users">
            {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
                this.props.users
            })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    users: state.users[0]
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Users);

// reducer
import { createReducer } from '../utils/helpers';
users: createReducer(initialData, {
    [FETCH_USERS](state, action) {
        return [action.payload, ...state];
    }
}),

//saga
function* watchFetchUsers() {
    while(true) {
        yield take(FETCH_USERS);
        try {
            const users = yield call(api.fetchUserData);
            yield put({ type:FETCH_USERS, payload: users });    
        } catch (err) {
            yield put({ type:SIGNOUT, status: err });
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is I can log this data with `console.log(this.props.users)` 
but I can't access the data within with `console.log(this.props.users.data)` or `console.log(this.props.users.data[0])` which came back with error 'data' undefined. Anyone can advice me what the problems are?

Comment: This question is confusing... Is `users` a array or a object?  Are this users fetched asynchronously?

Comment: the props users is an object. Yes, I have an action dispatched which fetch the users in componentWillMount() function.

Comment: Can you post your reducer code, so we can get a better understanding of the state?

Comment: Your screenshot shows two keys in your store - `data` and `included` - so `state.users` is going to be undefined.

Comment: @OrB I have added the flow of my codes, sorry wasn't being clear initially.

Comment: Is the payload an array or object? If I get it right, `state.users` is an array, and upon `FETCH_USERS` you're inserting the payload at `[0]` and spreading the existing users. So assuming the payload is an array, it will be `[]`, then turn into `[ [{ id: 1}, { id: 2}] ]`, then `[ [{ id: 3 }, { id: 4 }], { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]`. Is this what you're going for?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I can't reference the nested data initially is because the data is not rendered into the component yet as it was dispatching an action to retrieve the data asynchronously, hence returning 'data' undefined error. I got this to work by using state to check if the data is ready:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: null
    };
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            data: true
        });
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="users">
            {this.state.data ? React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
                users: this.props.users
            }) : ''}
        </div>
    );
}
```